Do any non-trivial functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ exist such that $\frac{\int_0^a f(x)dx}{\int_0^a g(x)dx}=\int_0^a\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}dx$?
Do non-trivial pairs of functions $f(x), g(x)$ exist which satisfy:
$\frac{\int_0^a f(x) dx}{\int_0^a g(x) dx} = \int_0^a \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} dx \ \ \ \forall a \neq 0 \ \ \ \ (1)$
where $g(x) \neq 0 \ \ \forall x$ and $\int_0^a g(x) dx \neq 0 \ \ \forall a$ ?
If they do, can one describe a process / method to come up with them?
($f(x) = 0$ works for any $g$, but I'll consider that to be trivial)

My approach so far has been: say $g(x)$ is given, and we wish to determine the corresponding $f(x)$, or determine that such an $f(x)$ cannot exist for that chosen $g(x)$.
First define $N_f = \int_0^a f(x) dx$ (so $N_f$ is a function of $a$) and similarly for $g$.
Taking derivatives w.r.t. $a$ on both sides of (1):
$\frac{f(a)}{N_g} -N_fN_g^{-2}g(a) = \frac{f(a)}{g(a)} \\
\frac{fN_g - N_f g}{N_g^2} = \frac{f(a)}{g(a)} \\
N_f = \frac{f(a)N_g -N_g^2 \frac{f(a)}{g(a)}}{g(a)}$
Now one can take another derivative of both sides, and end up with a differential equation (albeit a horrible one) for $f$ in terms of $g,N_g,f'$. However, when I try to solve this for some example $g$ functions, my resulting pair of functions does not satisfy (1). Perhaps there is something wrong with my approach, or maybe my algebra is just going wrong.

Okay, I will update my question. Your condition for the integral of g is implied by g having no roots.

Yes, you are quite right. Very nice question, by the way, I just wanted to clear up the trivialities and some technicalities

No worries! Thanks for mentioning the different cases. Also I'm not fully convinced by my own statement about g having no roots anymore, so I've added in the condition you stated, just in case.

Which value of $a$? If we're taking the Cauchy principal value, then $PV\int_0^2\frac{1}{x-1}dx=0$, but that's not a good example. One could construct a simple discontinuous function with an equal area above and below the $x$-axis that's still Riemann-integrable.

Yeah, after my comment I realised that my counterexample was wrong. Your discontinous function example is much better!

@teadawg1337 The question requests the equality to hold for any $a \neq 0$.

@mathcounterexamples.net I made a comment using a specific example (I said $\int_0^a \frac{1}{x-1} = 0$ for some a and hence I need to specify that $N_g$ is non-zero, thats what teadawg was referring to). I maybe shouldnt have deleted that comment, sorry.

@mathcounterexamples.net I showed a simple example of a $g(x)$ that has an integral of $0$ for some $a$, arguing in favor of the inclusion of $\int_0^a g(x)\neq0,\forall,a$ as a condition within the question. It was in reply to abluegiraffe's deleted comment, described above.

Some observations: If we instead do our integrals from $-\infty$ to $a$, then $f = e^{4x}$ and $g = e^{2x}$ work. I also believe that f(x) has no roots. Reason: If f(x) has roots, then Jim's h(x) has a root. Consider the first root of h(x) that we encounter after x=0, say at x=c. at this root, $g\int_0^c h dz = 0$, but g is non-zero so then the integral of h must be zero. But this cannot be, since c is the first root of h (unless h is discontinuous in the way @teadawg1337 described). Hence h(x) is either zero everywhere, or zero nowhere.

Let $h = \frac{f}{g}$.  Use this to get rid of $f$ and clear fractions; your question becomes: Do there exist $g, h$, with $g$ everywhere nonzero, such that
$$g(x)h(x) = g(x)\int_0^xh(z)dz + h(x)\int_0^xg(z)dz.$$
I don't have a complete answer, but I can say that if $h, g$ were representable by power series then $h = 0$.
To see this, let $g = \sum_i\alpha_ix^i$ and $h = \sum_i\beta_ix^i$.  Plug these into the above to get
$$\left(\sum_i\alpha_ix^i\right)\left(\sum_i\beta_ix^i\right) = \left(\sum_i\alpha_ix^i\right)\left(\sum_i\frac{\beta_i}{i + 1}x^{i + 1}\right) + \left(\sum_i\beta_ix^i\right)\left(\sum_i\frac{\alpha_i}{i + 1}x^{i + 1}\right).$$
There are no constant terms on the right, on the left the constant term gives $\alpha_0\beta_0 = 0$.  As $g(0) \neq 0$ we get $\alpha_0 \neq 0$ hence $\beta_0 = 0$.  Then by induction, if $\beta_i = 0$ for all $i < k$ then looking at the $k^\text{th}$ term gives $\alpha_0\beta_k = 0$ (the $+1$ in the exponent means the largest $h$ coefficient that can appear is $\beta_{k - 1}$) so $\beta_k = 0$.  We get that all $\beta_i$ are zero, hence $h = 0$.
We really only use the condition $g(0) \neq 0$.  I haven't looked at the details, but I suspect the same argument works when you center your power series at a different point, so you get that such a $g, h$ is nowhere representable by a power series.  I would guess that in fact there are no nontrivial solutions, but if there were they would be very weird functions.
